# Как закрывать спойлер нажатием в другю область?

Tags: javascript, html

Очень меня интересует как же закрыть спойлер нажатием на любую другую область, вне спойлера, ну и конечно что бы также закрывался и сам спойлер.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 jQuery('.spoiler-head').click(function(){
  $(this).parents('.spoiler-wrap').toggleClass("active").find('.spoiler-body').slideToggle();
 })
})
```

```css
.spoiler-wrap{background:#fff;margin: 0 0 8px;border:1px solid #efefef}
.spoiler-head{background:#efefef;cursor:pointer;padding:5px;}
.spoiler-body{padding:10px}
.spoiler-wrap.disabled .spoiler-body{display:none}
.spoiler-wrap.active{border-color:#57AA43}
.spoiler-wrap.active .spoiler-head{background:#57AA43;color:#fff}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="spoiler-wrap disabled">
  <div class="spoiler-head">Заголовок</div>
  <div class="spoiler-body">Текст</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.spoiler-head').click(function(){
    $(this).parents('.spoiler-wrap').toggleClass("active").find('.spoiler-body').slideToggle();
  });
  $(document).click(function(e){
    if (!$(e.target).hasClass('.spoiler-wrap') && !$(e.target).closest('.spoiler-wrap').length) {
      // $('.spoiler-wrap').hide('slide'); // - совсем убрать
      $('.spoiler-wrap').removeClass("active").find('.spoiler-body').hide('slide');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.spoiler-wrap{background:#fff;margin: 0 0 8px;border:1px solid #efefef}
.spoiler-head{background:#efefef;cursor:pointer;padding:5px;}
.spoiler-body{padding:10px}
.spoiler-wrap.disabled .spoiler-body{display:none}
.spoiler-wrap.active{border-color:#57AA43}
.spoiler-wrap.active .spoiler-head{background:#57AA43;color:#fff}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="spoiler-wrap disabled">
  <div class="spoiler-head">Заголовок</div>
  <div class="spoiler-body">Текст</div>
</div>
```

Comment: ой может я неправильно объяснил, но мне нужно его не скрывать совсем, а закрывать его кода он открытый

Comment: @AndriiSoldatenko Да, мне только сейчас пришло в голову, что Вы, возможно, это имели в виду.